# Error from running Hopkins function

Tags: r

The code below produces the following error. How do I fix that? Since I am using a generic function from clusterend. Do I make change to the data?

```
hopkins(DF2, n = nrow(DF2)-1, byrow=FALSE, header=FALSE)

**Error in if (sum(abs(error)) != 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE   needed

In addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)**
Warning messages:
1: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
2: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
3: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
4: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
5: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
6: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
7: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
8: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
9: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
10: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
11: In runif(n, min = c[i], max = d[i]) : NAs produced
```